# Which enemies are considered as "non-special"?

Tags: payday-2

The Joker skill (in the Mastermind tree) gives the possibility to turn "non-special" enemies.

> JOKER
>
> You can convert a non-special enemy to fight on your side. The enemy
>   must have surrendered in order for you to convert it.

Which enemies are "non-special" exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-special enemies are your regular police units, FBI agents, SWAT and hostage rescue units. Gangsters and guards are also considered non-special.

Special enemies (taser, sniper, bulldozer, shield and spook) can be marked for your team during an assault so that is another way to test whether or not an enemy is special.

[Source](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Enemies_%28Payday_2%29)